# What is the basic organization of web test(regression, speed, validation, etc.)?

Tags: testing, web, area, organization

I'm newbie in QA (testing)

I want to understand basic category or area of web test.

About this, I found a web site.
http://www.softwareqatest.com/qatweb1.html

=============================================
Organization of Web Test Tools Listing - this tools listing has been loosely organized into the following categories:

Load and Performance Test Tools

Page Speed Testing Tools

Mobile Web/App Testing Tools

Link Checkers

HTML Validators

Web Accessibility Testing Tools

Web Services Test Tools

Cross-Browser Testing Tools/Services

Web Functional/Regression Test Tools
Web Site Security Test Tools

External Site Monitoring Services

Web Site Management Tools

## Log Analysis Tools

I might think these are web site test area but it is not MECE.

Please give me more advice.

Comment: What u actually wants

Answer (score 0):

These tools are sufficient to test all areas as for MECE you have to write test cases and check. These are depends on functionality not on Tools.

With add on this:

There are different websites which provide mobiles online to test application some are free and some have premium accounts

- pCloudy
- bitbar
- Experitest etc..

For automation you have to use tools like:

- Appium for Android and IOS
- Robotium for Android
- MonkeyTalk
- Selendroid for Android